# Pythonic way to check that the lengths of lots of lists are the same

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have a number of lists that I'm going to use in my program, but I need to be sure that they are all the same length, or I'm going to get problems later on in my code.

What's the best way to do this in Python?

For example, if I have three lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b']
c = [5, 6, 7]
```

I could do something like:

```
l = [len(a), len(b), len(c)]
if max(l) == min(l):
   # They're the same
```

Is there a better or more Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming you have a non-empty list of lists, e.g.

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'], [5, 6, 7]]
```

you could use

```
n = len(my_list[0])
if all(len(x) == n for x in my_list):
    # whatever
```

This will short-circuit, so it will stop checking when the first list with a wrong length is encountered.

Comment: +1 for possible exit as early as `my_list[1]`...some others are lacking this.

Answer (score 9):

```
len(set(len(x) for x in l)) <= 1
```

Latter I ended up writing:

```
def some(x):
    """Replacement for len(set(x)) > 1"""

    if isinstance(x, (set, frozenset)):
       return len(x) > 1

    s = set()
    for e in x:
        s.add(e)
        if len(s) > 1:
            return True
    return False

def lone(x):
    """Replacement for len(set(x)) <= 1"""
    return not some(x)
```

Which allows the above to be written as:

```
lone(len(x) for x in l)
```

This will stop taking the lengths of the lists as soon as it finds a list with a different length.

Comment: Could do `<= 1` to handle the case when `l` is empty…

Answer (score 7):

A bit of functional Python:

```
>>> len(set(map(len, (a, b, c)))) == 1
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Each call to `max` and `min` will traverse the whole list, but you don't really need to do that; you can check for the desired property with one traversal:

```
def allsamelength(lst_of_lsts):
    if len(lst_of_lsts) in (0,1): return True
    lfst = len(lst_of_lsts[0])
    return all(len(lst) == lfst for lst in lst_of_lsts[1:])
```

This will also short-circuit if one of the lists has a different length from the first.

Answer (score 0):

If l is list of lengths:

```
l = [len(a), len(b), len(c)]
if len(set(l))==1:
    print 'Yay. List lengths are same.'
```

Otherwise, using the original lists, one could create a list of lists:

```
d=[a,b,c]
if len(set(len(x) for x in d)) ==1:
    print 'Yay. List lengths are same.'
```